# Module has no exported member Vue Ts

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm trying to import my own types inside my component, and something weird it's happening. So if I do :

**Types**

```
export type Size = 'foo' |'foo' | 'foo' | 'foo';
export type Type = 'foo' | 'foo' | 'foo' | 'foo';
export type State = 'foo'
```

**Component**

```
    import { Size, State, Type } from '@/typings/button-type';
    
    props: {
            size: {
                default: 'foo',
                type: String as PropType<Size>
            },
            state: {
                default: 'foo',
                type: String as PropType<State>
            },
            type: {
                default: 'foo',
                type: String as PropType<Type>
            }
        },
```

This works just fine.
But now that I wanted to add the type Color, or just put all the types inside a button type that I want to create and use them; I'm getting an error. I don't know why it works with those 3 types and not the others.

***Types Failed***

```
    export type MyOwnType = {
        color: Color;
        size: Size;
        type: Type;
        state: State;
    }

type Color = 'foo' | 'foo';
type Size = 'foo' |'foo' | 'foo' | 'foo';
type Type = 'foo' | 'foo' | 'foo' | 'foo';
type State = 'foo'
```

```
export type Color = 'foo' | 'foo';
export type Size = 'foo' |'foo' | 'foo' | 'foo';
export type Type = 'foo' | 'foo' | 'foo' | 'foo';
export type State = 'foo'
```

And the I try to do:

```
            color: {
                default: 'foo',
                type: String as PropType<Color>
            }
```

or the same with the Object like PropType<MyOwnType['size']> I get the same error

***Error***

```
src/components/Btn/Btn.vue:11:14
TS2305: Module '"../../typings/button-type"' has no exported member 'Color'.
     9 |     import { defineComponent, computed, PropType } from '@vue/runtime-core';
    10 |     import { useI18n } from 'vue-i18n';
  > 11 |     import { Color, Size, State, Type } from '@/typings/button-type';
       |              ^^^^^
```

Either Color, or MyOwnType or Foo... has no exported member.

Any idea?

Comment: Hi! If your code must work perfectly, but it does not, you can try to relad your IDE and redo the import.
If you still has the problem you may consider to provide us a code that is [complete, minimal, and reproducable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You can use codesandbox.io or something similar.